# how to Assign Multiple Roles for a user in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I know how to assign a single role for a user. But coming to the multiple roles for a user is not working...Is wordpress gives this facility or not.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For completeness, this *is* possible!

```
 $theUser = new WP_User($userId);
 $theUser->add_role( $role );
```

Comment: Note that the **Wordpress Admin UI does not support multiple roles** even though the code does. Thus, **if the user is ever saved again via the Wordpress Admin UI**, only the role selected in the Roles dropdown will be stored, all other roles will be removed.

Comment: Is it possible to hook the user save event - allowing a manager to have the required additional roles added back?

Answer (score 33):

Yes, WordPress allows this. You can do it in your code:

```php
    $someone = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $someone->add_role( 'role-1' );
    $someone->add_role( 'role-2' );
```

You can also use a plugin such as [Multiple Roles](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-roles/). The plugin 
will transform the select dropdown into checkboxes.

[image: WordPress — Role selection checkboxes]

Comment: Now I would use the "Members" plugin by MemberPress, but similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in Wordpress currently, as this is how the core role mapping is designed. You can however create "combination" roles, but this might lead to a large number of roles when you have a lot of core roles to combine.

Another option would be using a plugin such as [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/), which can help you giving more control of Wordpress' role mapping.