# Multiple role user registration in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How to register user with seperate roles in WordPress. For example: Register as "doctor" AND register as "patient".

Comment: Better you can manage  and assign capability based role.

Comment: As a basic WordPress user, it appears to me that you haven't done *ANY* research or tried anything. Also this is off-topic and would belong to super-user if it weren't such a low-quality question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420705/how-to-assign-multiple-roles-for-a-user-in-wordpress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Assign Multiple Roles for a user in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420705/how-to-assign-multiple-roles-for-a-user-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very poor question my friend. Stackoverflow is not an all-in-one magic solution site. You should show what you have tried and we help you out with a specific problem.

However what you want to achieve is easily possible (pseudo code):

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
$u = get_user($user_id);
$u->add_role( 'doctor' );
$u->add_role( 'patient' );

}
```

Comment: Please help me . I'm new to web developement and I heard about WordPress 3 day ago.
I want to create a site for golf events registration.
Points are
1.user registration for viewing and  Book a event.
2.Host registration for host the event 
3.sponser registration for adding new event

Comment: Thats a lot of things to learn. Your options: 1) Just use a Plugin 2) Write a Plugin mostly independent of WordPress 3) Learn WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/ , https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities HF & GL!